# How to compare the performance of web frameworks

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, performance, asp.net-mvc-3, frameworks

I want to compare the performance of some web frameworks (Ruby on Rails and ASP MVC3) but I don't know how to get started... Should I measure how fast each framework renders e 10k long loop or how fast its renders 10k lines of html? Are there maybe programs that can help you with this? Also how can the server load be monitored? Any help is appreciated!

Thijs

Comment: large sites run both - whats your team's experience and hardware available?

Comment: Its not in team, I just want to create some tests of my own to compare the 2 frameworks.

Answer (score 3):

With respect, this is an unanswerable question.  Is a Porche faster than a Prius?  Well, no, not when the Porche is in the shop :-).

The answer depends on what you're trying to accomplish, how you do it, and how you code it.  For example, Rails goes out of its way to transparently cache as much as it can, and then makes it trivially easy to cache stuff on your command.  Of course there's a way to do the same in ASP MVC3, but is it as easy?

Can you find, hire, and train a suitable team in that knows how to use the framework?  What's the culture of the organization (Windows or Unix?).  I could write a really fast application in MS-Access and the same application poorly in Rails against a high-performance database and the MS-Access app would win.  It's far from a given that an application will be written well, optimized, or whatever.

These days, a well-written application is typically performance bound on data I/O, and if this is the case, then it's which database you use that might matter.  The loop-test you propose would test almost nothing, unless you're writing an application that calculates pi to the billionth place, or something.

I am sure there are published benchmarks of application frameworks available, but again, they need to make assumptions about what the application actually has to do.

The reality is that any reasonable framework (which includes both of the two you mention) is likely to be as fast as necessary for most scenarios, and again, what you do, and how you architect and implement it are the far more likely culprits for performance problems.

Once you do choose, there's a great (awesome) tool called NewRelic RPM which works with several frameworks -- I use it with Rails, and it gives you internal metrics at a level of detail that is beyond belief.

I don't mean to be glib, or unhelpful.  But this is a little bit of a sore spot for me -- in so many cases people say "we should use foo instead of bar because foo's faster", and weeks go by as bar is replaced by foo.  And then there are little incompatibilities.  And an unexpected bug.  And then, well, for some reason the new one is a little slower.  And then after it gets optimized, it's finally just as fast.

I'll step down from my soapbox now :-)

Comment: Thanks for the link to Newrelic! Are there any free alternatives?

Comment: Nothing in M$ land, I doubt.  But there are scores of performance measuring, monitoring, instrumenting and other tools in the "nothin' beats free" world of Linux.  Heck, Rails has pretty much built-in performance tools in its logging, and that comes out of the box.  Actually, at least for Rails, NewRelic had a free version that developers could use -- not as immensely powerful as their server-based versions, but still mind-blowingly cool.